# How to show describe a bijection between 2 infinite intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

I am attempting to find a bijection between $(0,1/2)$ and $(2,\infty)$ in a addition to $(0,\infty)$ and $(2,\infty)$. I understand how to solve this when all of the ranges and bounded by integers, its pretty easy to find a linear map, but how are you supposed to solve it when infinity is involved?

Answer (score 1):

I find the function $x \to \frac{1}{x}$ most easy to manipulate for this kind of intervals. Draw a graph and move the hyperbola around to fit into the intervals.

Define $f:(0,\frac{1}{2}) \to (2,\infty)$ by $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{2}}$

Define $g:(0,\infty) \to (2,\infty)$ by $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}+2$

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, consider $x\to\frac{1}{x}$. For the second one consider $x\to x+2$.

Comment: I mean, sure you've given an answer, but I think what he wants is more of an intuitive understanding.